# Pi - Detecting hdmi out or power interrupted

Tags: raspbmc, python, usb-power

Does anyone know of a way to script this?

The idea being that using raspbmc / hdmi to TV / Tv USB to Pi mini USB (with a battery for buffer)...

You could have your Pi running off the tv's usb. When the TV powers down the pi uses the battery, detects the lack of power or lack of hdmi output and shuts itself down.

Ideas?

Comment: Does the TV usb go off when the TV goes off? It might not and if so, an option would be to get a IR receiver and turn off when it gets the off signal from the remote.

Comment: That's a good question, I hadn't even considered that it might not, I am actually talking about standby rather than off. So it might not, will check now.

Comment: Hmm interesting. . TV on = USB working. Put on standby = Still working. Turn off main TV switch = no USB. Turn on main switch (which goes on standby) = no USB. Its a little inconsistant :'( which means ideally I could still do with a script.

Comment: Wow that is quite inconsistent :P Also, the TV does supply enough power for the Pi, right? Another idea just came into my head: you know those power strips that turn off other devices when you turn off the TV, maybe you could use one of those for the pi?

Comment: Yeah no problem powering it from the Tv as far as I could see. Not sure what you mean by strip? The ir idea might work but I was hoping for a script running on the pi which detects a change in port state.